# Dynamic forms not working in zeppelin spark interpreter

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have an instance of zeppelin that I built using from source(0.8.0-SNAPSHOT).
If I try to run this:

%md
Hello ${name}
I get a text input box,

But this,

%spark
println("Hello "+z.input("name"))

or

%livy
var t = spark.sql("select * MYTABLE where field1='${fieldValue}'")
t.show()

does not give input text boxes.

This was working in zeppelin-0.7.3

What could be the reason for the same?

Answer (score 0):

The second should work. The third won't work because livy doesn't support ZeppelinContext.

Comment: I tried the third in zeppelin-0.7.3 and it works, but somehow does not in zeppelin-0.8.0-SNAPSHOT